# How to get jquery to reuse element identities re-loaded via AJAX correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm not sure I've diagnosed this problem correctly.

I have a jquery dialogue that pops up another jquery dialog.  When I pop up the inner dialog
once everything seems to work.  when I close both dialogues and reopen them the "save" button on the
inner dialogue does not work right -- in particular it doesn't close the dialog.

What I think is happening: The second time the content for the second dialogue is reloaded
via AJAX using the same DOM id's as the first time, and when jquery tries to close the dialogue
it tries to close the "old" dialogue which no longer exists (or at least is not visible).

Am I right?  If so how to get jquery to forget the old element and use the new one?

If you want to see the problem yourself:

1. go to http://ibidreview.appspot.com/Teach/Edit?eid=1DemoE&owner=
2. click the first "change question" button.  First dialog should show.
3. click the "html" pseudo-link.  Second dialog should show.
4. click "save" on inner dialog.  Inner dialog should close
5. click "change" on first dialog.  First dialog should close.
6. Now repeat steps 2,3,4 and notice that on step 4 the inner dialog does not close.

I will stop trying to fix this for a while so the steps will work the same... Thanks in advance!

Comment: you gave us a localhost link...

Comment: How do you declare event click on save button? With jQuery using .click() ?

Comment: Cesar: button declaration looks like this: $("#popDiv_FullTargetInput").dialog ({
        autoOpen : false
        ,buttons : { "save": onSave_FullTargetInput }
        ,minWidth : 300
        ,width : 800
    });

Comment: Alright, I don't know how to fix this, but I've discovered a work around is to always use new names for elements loaded via ajax.  When I do this the problem goes away.  It's annoing, but I guess I can live with it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `live()` event handler. This will ensure that the element will still fire the event after being destroyed or recreated. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Use something like this:

```
$(button).live('click', function() {
   $(form).save(); //save the form
   $(menu).close(); //close the menu
});
```

Comment: I'm confused by this answer.  I don't know how to identify the button since it is created by jQueryUI like this $("#popDiv_FullTargetInput").dialog ({
        autoOpen : false
        ,buttons : { "save": onSave_FullTargetInput }
        ,minWidth : 300
        ,width : 800
    });
-- however I will look at the live event handler and see if I can grok it.